# What does "synchronous dynamic coupling" mean?

Tags: architecture

In "Software Architecture: The Hard Parts", Architecture quantum is defined as:

> An architecture quantum is an independently deployable artifact with
> high functional cohesion, high static coupling, and **synchronous
> dynamic coupling**. A common example of an architecture quantum is a
> well-formed microservice within a workflow.

It also says,

> synchronous coupling at runtime—in other words, the behavior of
> architecture quanta as they interact with one another to form
> workflows within a distributed architecture.

"Fundamentals of Software Architecture" says:

> Synchronous connascence implies synchronous calls within an
> application context or between distributed services that form this
> architecture quantum. For example, if one service in a microservices
> architecture calls another one synchronously, each service cannot
> exhibit extreme differences in operational architecture
> characteristics. If the caller is much more scalable than the callee,
> timeouts and other reliability concerns will occur. Thus, synchronous
> calls create dynamic connascence for the length of the call—if one is
> waiting for the other, their operational architecture characteristics
> must be the same for the duration of the call.

What I got from these books is,

- **Dynamic coupling** refers to how architecture parts call one another: what kind of communication, what information is passed, strictness of contracts, and so on. Dynamic coupling represents how quanta communicate at runtime, either synchronously or asynchronously. Static coupling analyzes operational dependencies, and dynamic coupling analyzes communication dependencies.
- **Synchronous communication** requires the requestor to wait for the response from the receiver.
- **operational architecture characteristics** is performance, scale, elasticity, reliability, and so on.

So, I understand Synchronous communication. I also understand Dynamic coupling. Somehow, I did not get what "synchronous dynamic coupling" mean. why "synchronous dynamic coupling" is ok for "architecture quantum" but "asynchronous dynamic coupling" is not?

Comment: Quite frankly it does not make too much sense for me as well. I can imagine it is a typo (auto-correct) for *simultaneously*.

Comment: Synchronous communication couples components together so that they cannot be independent quanta. Such communication forms a subset of synchronous dynamic couplings.

I think _synchronous dynamic coupling_ is the author trying to be more general, but I can't think of an instance of synchronous dynamic coupling that isn't synchronous communication. Maybe I should read further into the book haha